# Validate form called through another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

Im writing a blog engine, So I have a post view (show.html.erb) that shows a post, comments list and a comments form.

I call the form this way:

```
<%= render :partial => 'comments/form', :locals => {:comment => @post.comments.new} %>
```

Im not sure if passing the comment that way is correct, but at least I get the post_id on the new comment.

This is my form (_form.html.erb on comments view):

```
<%= form_for comment, :action => "create" do |f| %>
    <% if comment.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being added:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :post_id %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :url %>
    <%= f.text_field :url %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </p>
  <p class="no-border">
    <%= f.submit "Post", :class => "button" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

And this the action:

```
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
      end
    end
  end
```

A bit verbose but I want to add more stuff.

I can add comments perfectly but I can't view validation errors.

I leave all blank (my model have validation stuff) and I see that the comment created in the **create** action have the errors and go to the **else** path.

But... The form doesn't show any errors.

I think that I have an object with the erorrs but when I redirect back, the object I pass to the form is a new one again and doesn't have the errors.

So, where is the problem?

EDIT: Extra stuff:

Im my show.html.erb I also have this (before the form):

```
<ol class="commentlist">
  <%= render @post.comments %>
</ol>
```

So, When in the **show** action I put the extra variable:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @comment = @post.comments.new
```

It seems that the render wants to render the empty comment too and make an exception.

How to bypass that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you redirect back, you are calling the `PostsController#show` action again which will reset all of the instance variables. If you wanted to save state after the failed `CommentsController#create` call, you would need to call `render 'posts/show'` instead of `redirect :back` which would reuse the instance variables which were declared in the current action

```
def create
   # assuming you have nested the comments routes underneath posts...
   @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
   @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])

   respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
         format.html { redirect_to :back }
      else
         format.html do
            # remember to declare any instance variables that PostsController#show requires
            # e.g. @post = ...
            render 'posts/show'
         end
      end
   end
end
```

You would also need to make sure that the partial uses `@comment` instead of creating a new comment each time

```
<%= render :partial => 'comments/form', :locals => {:comment => @comment } %>
```

And make sure the `PostsController` declares `@comment`

```
# e.g. inside PostsController
def show
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   @comment = Comment.new
end
```

The most important thing to remember is to make sure that the code inside the failed `create` call initializes all the instance variables that the `PostsController#show` action template requires otherwise you'll get errors.

Comment: Awesome answer. I just have another question. If I need to create the @post inside the create method, I need the post id. Is that id somewhere inside the request to create?

Comment: Assuming you have nested your routes, then you should have access to it via ```params[:post_id]```. Check ```rake routes``` to make sure that your comment paths are nested beneath a post, e.g., ```posts/1/comments```

Comment: Nop, I don't have that, this is my first project. But I will research that. Otoh, I updated the question because I have an extra problem with your solution that I forgot to comment before.

Comment: I nested the routes but I still have the show problem (See my updated question). the list will render my current comments and will try to render the new comment too or the comment with validation errors. I guess I need to try another approach to render my comment list.

Comment: Well, Creating a new comment on show and assigning it the post id by hand and creating a new comment from params (not build) in create seems to work.